# What causes the 130-133Hz hum in my KRK VXT6 monitors?

Tags: ableton, speakers, noise, monitors

I bought a new pair of [KRK VXT6 monitors](http://www.krksys.com/krk-studio-monitor-speakers/vxt/vxt6.html) last week and I think they sound amazing, but upon listening to some songs, I hear a weird noise specifically in the bass.

I decided to analyze the weird sound that I heard with a spectrum analyzer (the ableton live spectrum).

I saw that the weird sound comes around 130-133 Hz.

I want to know if someone else gets that sound too.  Is it normal in this speaker, or is it some technical issue? (I bought the speakers in EEUU and I live in Venezuelaso it would be quite hard to return this item)

Answer (score 1):

Are you examining your speakers with a sine sweep, or just your music?

It is possible that the music was mastered strangely, and the monitors are just showing that to you. If the problem persists as you (slowly) sweep a sine wave from 50 Hz to 200 Hz, then you should contact KRK's technical support to see what they recommend.

More on testing:

What does your spectrum analyzer look like while you are sweeping the sine wave? At 50Hz, you should see a single narrow peak at 50 Hz. Based on what you are describing, around 120-140Hz you are probably seeing something more like a mountain range. Also, is the peak in this distorted range much higher or lower than at other frequencies?

Comment: all songs that i hear was in 320kbps, the songs are from different kind of generes all like dubstep, electro house, deep house, nu disco. I tasted the monitors with a sine wave from 50hz to 200hz, i got the same sound around the 120hz until 140hz. if i try to describe the sound i think it is exaggerated in the bass, like the vibration is just too high when he reproduce that signal. i dont know if i use the right terminology but for someone like me is hard because i'm new at this.

Comment: What does your spectrum analyzer look like while you are sweeping the sine wave? At 50Hz, you should see a single narrow peak at 50 Hz. Based on what you are describing, around 120-140Hz you are probably seeing something more like a mountain range. Also, is the peak in this distorted range much higher or lower than at other frequencies?

Comment: would a picture or a video help??

Comment: At this point, I would contact KRK support. I think you have more than enough information for them to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking its not your monitors but your room. Try listening to your monitors in a different room, preferably a bigger one with different dimensions. My guess is that the low frequency noise won't be there, or it will be in a different frequency range.

What you're most likely hearing is a build up standing waves due to reflections within the room. The best way to fix this is to add acoustic treatment such as Auralex foam. but more specifically bass traps. Bass traps are special treatments that deaden reflections of low frequencies, preventing them from bouncing all over your room and building up in certain frequency ranges.

I recommend Mike Senior's Mix Secrets For The Small Studio. Has some great information about how to set up and properly treat your room. Your monitors are worthless if you don't treat your room. Best of luck.